# Do shots fired before the match starts count towards your end-of-game statistics?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, there is short countdown for a few minutes before the match begins. During this time, the defending team is allowed to roam the map to set up their defenses, while the attacking team sits in a small lobby until the game starts and the doors open. (Or in KotH-type maps, both teams wait in a lobby.)

While players wait, it's not uncommon for them to fire off random shots, especially since a lot of the environment is destructable (it's entertaining to watch plush onions sail through the air in the arcade).

Do shots fired before the match starts count towards accuracy statistics at the end of the game?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, I've done this with Roadhog shift (Hook) as I wanted to know if this counted towards the end game statistics.

It appears it doesn't start counting them until the match begins as even though I spammed out the abilities and shooting it would only show the stats after, 100% if I landed it 0% if I missed but 50% if I hit the second shot out of 2 regardless how much I spammed during the prep stage.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence and conclusion. How many times did you try to hook during the game? Did you do this in multiple games?

Comment: +1, Not exactly a detailed listing of your methods and results, but I guess that's clear enough.

Comment: I will look at starting to do more science and numbers in the future.

Comment: @DCShannon: Upon my fourth reading, I think he's saying he used Hook many times in prep, and once during the match, and since accuracy always showed 0% or 100%, it must not be measuring the bits during warmup.

Comment: @MooingDuck Basically. There's an implication that it was done on multiple games, and at least some of the time it was not 0/1 or 1/1, but instead 1/2, but that in none of these trials did the ratio include the hook spams in the warmup area.

Answer (score 5):

Backing up the previous answer, no. I noticed it because your first 5 (well, hopefully 5!) shields as Symmetra won't count if you apply them before the match starts.

Comment: That's kinda garbage, because Symmetra's shields (unlike shots fired before the match) most definitely affect play during the match. What are you supposed to do, wait until you're knee-deep in combat to start throwing around shields?

Comment: I mean they work you just don't get credit for them on the score screen.

Comment: I realize that -- I'm saying that since they affect the actual match play, you should get credit :P

Comment: Oh yeah, agreed 100%.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of examples:

1. Death don´t count before the match starts (Killed myself with pharra in the no heal zone of spawn)
2. Healing done doesn´t count ( Buddy healed me while i tried to suicide without getting the points added)

We could add a lot more examples but in the end we could make it short in saying that the statistics start with the match starting (as @Bandito Dorito said)