# Healing Before Match Starts

Tags: overwatch

If a character like Pharah or Junkrat hurts themselves in spawn, before the round starts, and Mercy/Zenyatta/Lucio heals them, will it count towards their healing stats for that game?

Comment: In short: no. In long: [related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272018/do-shots-fired-before-the-match-starts-count-towards-your-end-of-game-statistics)

Comment: We tried this with friends with every healers, it doesn't works, neither in attack if the spawn isn't a full heal zone, neither in defense where you totally are out of spawn. We tried this in order to stack ults before the game start and it doesn't. All ults and stats seems to be unactive before the offenders doors opens. I deleted answer because of the last "overwatch" question

Comment: Well, this wasn't a dupe until 9 hours ago, when an answer was given in the linked thread.

Answer (score 1):

**No it doesn't**

All kill and heal stats are turned off before the start of the game.

Strangely enough, if you manage to glitch into the enemy spawn during a match (like a Tracer teleport) then the kills inside the spawn does count.